# AWS elasticbeanstalk worker received not allowed requests and stop to work. It need to be restart manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker environment with SQS and cronjobs to do what I want.

But sometimes, my environment bug and stop to work (it needs to be restarted manually) because it received some unknown requests (not send by me of course) :

```
196.52.43.55 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:00:33:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 226 "-" "-"
81.196.3.208 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:01:45:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 4576 "-" "-"
195.154.214.162 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:03:43:21 +0000] "GET //recordings/modules/phonefeatures.module HTTP/1.1" 404 471 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64"
195.154.214.162 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:04:54:27 +0000] "GET //recordings/modules/phonefeatures.module HTTP/1.1" 404 471 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-696.1.1.el6.x86_64"
```

Example of cron job I executed every minute

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:00:14:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/search/detailsHTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:00:14:59 +0000] "POST /workers/cron/positions HTTP/1.1" 200 60 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [09/Jun/2017:00:15:01 +0000] "POST /queue/received HTTP/1.1" 200 10 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"
```

Do you have a solution for me? Do I need to change my VPC and/or EC2 group security?

My architecture is one Elasticsearch Application and one Elasticsearch Worker.

Thank you very much

Comment: Any server that's exposed to the public internet will receive requests like those - they are (thankfully) weak attempts to hack your server, and there's not a lot you can do about them. That being said, there's no need for your worker environment to be accepting connections from the outside world. You can safely remove the inbound rule that's listening on port 80. However, a couple of 404s shouldn't be breaking your instance badly enough to require a restart...

Comment: Thanks brian, I believed it was possible to have a private subnet to only receive a request of my master application. But if I delete inbound rule of 80, my cron job will not work (I think).

Comment: None of my EB worker instances have a port 80 rule, and they work fine with cron. Your web instance does not communicate directly with the worker instance, and the worker instance does not need any security group rules to POST messages to itself.

Comment: Hi brian, when I delete the port 80 rule for the worker, I don't know why but it doesn't save on my RDS ddb the data.

Comment: @MatinGarrix Do u know what GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 226 error mean?